# API versioning using Wildcard Sub-domains

Tags: nginx, wildcard-subdomain

I don't want to add any versioning logic to the API.
If I use Wildcard Sub-domains and regex in nginx.conf to determine subdomain part, I can route the request to specific directory. Here is the config:

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name .api.domain.com;

        set $version $host;

        if ($version ~ "^(.+).api.domain.com") {
                set $version $1;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/$version-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/$version-error.log info;

        location / {
                root /opt/webapps/app_$version/www/;
                index index.php;
        }

}
```

Question: Is there any disadvantage of such technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found better way - named captures in server_name:

```
server {

  server_name ~^(?<version>.+).test$;
  root /your-path/$version.test;

}
```

This is method is better because:

1. [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil)
2. It is much more cleaner